# Algorithm to visualize a diagram on 2D plane?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, visualization

Some program has a GUI allowing users to edit a "diagram", like `Blender`:

[image]

If I have the underlying data structure(possibly a directed graph?), how to draw a clean diagram on screen without overlaying nodes/confusing users? Are there some known algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), it has many build-in diagram layout algorithms available. As it is an open source project, I believe you can find useful information there.